# Api authentication triggers preflight so i cannot set cookies

Tags: angular, laravel, cookies, http-headers, access-control

I try to login from an angular api to a laravel app using a password grant. Therefore i am doing a post request using my username and password to a proxy script that wil also send my client id and client secret to the oAuth server. Because i want to store an encrypted version of the access token and refresh token in a cookie, i set the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header in my post request along with the regular cors headers. But when i do this, the post request is not a so called "simple" post request anymore and the browser does send a preflight OPTIONS request auotmatically. The downside of this request is that it does not allow the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header being set. If you do you get an error. So, whats the solution to this?

I've found a workaround but i don't like it: I don't send the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header now and don't try to return cookies. Instead i put the data i want to have in the cookies (the encrypted tokens) in the body of the response. Then i read the body with angular and manually set the cookies.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is a *response* header **not** a request header. In other words, that should be set by the server. The OPTION request is sent by the user-agent to see *what are my options in this scenario?* Once this negotiation/handshake is done, IF the user-agent sees that it is given the "go-ahead" by the server, by comparing the COR headers with the `Access-Allow-*` response headers, it proceeds with the intended cross-origin request.

Answer (score 0):

The method you describe at the end is fine so long as you're connected via https, of course. It's not uncommon to transport tokens in query strings also, although personally I don't care for that method.

Does the server you're sending the request to not have cors configured correctly? It should allow for a preflight request.

Comment: It allows preflight requests but the thing is that when i send my username and password via a post request, i want to have cookies back, storing the encrypted access and refresh tokens. And for that to work i need to set the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header. And because i set it, it sends the OPTIONS request. and somehow magically that options request also does have the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials set which isn't allowed. This results in my request being canceled.

Are you suggesting that a OPTIONS request should allow the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header?

Comment: No, its my understanding that options requests should always be excluded from authentication. Your server should  respond with a 200 or 204. Server side, is access control allow origin set to the actual host, or wildcard *?

Comment: Ok, i don't see how i would prevent te browser from sending the preflight options request. It sends it automatically just before i send the post request containing my credentials. It does this because i have set the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header. When i leave it out from the post request, no options preflight request is sent but when i get the cookies back (i see them in the response), it won't store them.